# Slow Azure storage access internationally

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I work for an Australian based company (but globally accessed.) and we currently have a site hosted in the Australian East regions that I am migrating to a new azure bizspark subscription.  Unfortunately the new bizspark subscription doesn't allow databases created in Australian regions and so i have created the new site in West US 2 region.

The site is a photo management portal that consists of Web App, Database and storage account for the storage of photos that can range up to 20mb in size each.

The images are available on the site through a link to the direct blobUrl and can be downloaded on bulk as a ZIP file that the system builds on the fly.

However in the new site I am getting significant delays in accessing the images. I get the following speeds. These are slow speeds cos i have slow internet.  But that is another issue to be resolved. I'm testing both on the same connection.

Downloading the blob directly through the Bloburl 20kb to 30kb (250+ on the Aust East site.)
Downloading the zip file 50kb-150kb (500+ on the Aust East site. )

Can anyone shed any light on why there is a significant different in the speeds.  Is it just because of the distance? Are there tips and tricks for global sites that will minimise download latency internationally.

For testing purposes i have tested spinning up the storage account in both the Aust East and West US 2 sites and testing the migrated site. When in the Aust region the direct bloburl access is faster (but still not as fast as the old site) but the Download to Zip is slower again.  I'm guessing this would be because its not in the same region as the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look into creating CDN ( Content Delivery Networks). They are designed to solve the problem of latency. It keeps the cached version of its contents in geogrpahic locations. Look at this as it might solve your issue.

[Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-new-endpoint)

This should help in resolving your issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Ill start reading.  My main concern is the size limit.  We have galleries roughly 800mb and larger.  We would soon run out of space.  need to see what is the best option